# Dropzone with Laravel. Large files cause 500 error

Tags: reactjs, dropzone.js, laravel-5.7

I have increased these settings in *php.ini*:

```
memory_limit = 500M
post_max_size = 256M
upload_max_filesize = 256M
```

The config settings for *dropzone.js* are:

```
acceptedFiles: 'text/csv',
timeout: 3000000,
maxFilesize: 128, // MB
```

Trying to upload 50MB csv files.

File seems to upload fine but I immediately get a 500 error from server (local LAMP server) with no content in the response.

As it's giving a 500 error immediately upon successful upload, I know it's not a timeout issue. The upload takes approx 2 seconds. Small *.csv* files work fine.

Any ideas/thoughts?!

Comment: Have you checked your `laravel.log` file for an exception?

Comment: Nothing is put in the laravel.log which is a bit odd

Comment: I'm now looking at chunking it but still got similar issues

Comment: Do you have the `mbstring` php extension enabled? (you can check with `phpinfo()`). Also, see if your php log (separate from laravel log) or apache log have any more information

Comment: Yes, `mbstring` is enabled. Laravel requires it anyway if I remember correctly. I have found that increasing the `memory_limit` to `1024M` is better. But now have a different error!

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Also, what might mbstring have to do with this problem?